# Preposition usage with “system”, or a circumstance

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

As a programmer, my job frequently asks me to write reports. I'm confused about the usage of prepositions with “system” and other circumstance terms.

For instance, which should it be?

> … background image is missing **in** the QA system.

or

> … background image is missing **under** the QA system.

---

> I wouldn't jog **in** this weather.

or

> I wouldn't jog **under** this weather.

Comment: Do you mean that the QA system fails to display its background image, or do you really  mean the CM system, and your project's background image has not been properly checked-in to the CM system?   "jog **in** this weather" is correct.

Comment: OR maybe the QA system fails to mention the background image in its audit report...

Comment: I'm a programmer too! (anyway)
So _background image is missing in QA system_ means there is no background image **in** the system. Meanwhile, _background image is missing under QA system_ means because of this QA system existence, the background image is missing.

Comment: @Jim, i mean background image cannot be displayed in QA system. Yea as you said, fails to display. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Safira Thank you very much, that helps a lot. So under will be regard as 'because of'/'Due to', am i right?

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much it. Shall I put this into an answer then? So the viewer will know the answer you're looking for?

Comment: _Under_ could also be used in a hiearchy. Suppose we are dealing with project management software, with three main functions: QA, CM, and PM. The images are showing up fine under CM and PM (and all of their sub-pages), but "the image is missing _under_ the QA system." That's somewhat contrived but still viable.

Comment: @Safira Yea, put it into an answer.

Comment: @J.R. Thank you for replying. So 'in' would be better and sounds more native?

Comment: @Ray - Not enough information given to say for sure. I'm not sure what kind of "system" you are talking about, so I'm not sure about which preposition would be ideal to use. I do think 'in' sounds like a safe bet, though.

Comment: Footnote: having just read your comment to Wendi, I think _in_ is the word you are looking for.

Comment: @Ray-Von-Mice: I've put it into an answer, I'd be glad if you accept it ;)

Answer (score -2):

*Under* doesn't make sense in either sentence. The way your first example reads is that "QA system" is some kind of image, and that there is supposed to be a background image appearing below it, but it doesn't show up. But since a QA system is *not* an image, that doesn't make any sense. *In* doesn't really work either. It doesn't make sense to be missing an image in a system. You can be missing an image *on the QA screen* or *on the QA page*. I can't 100% determine what you're trying to say here, even after reading comments on the question. But maybe you mean something like this:

> The background image is missing on the QA page.

This means that in your application there is a page dedicated to QA, and this page's background image has failed to load.

Your second question is pretty different; I know both are re: "in vs under", but since neither in nor under make sense in the first case, it's not really the same. Regardless, the correct word to use with *weather* is *in*:

> I wouldn't jog in this weather.

We go *out in the rain* and *out in bad weather*. Once you're outside, you're *in* whatever type of inclement weather there is. *Under* doesn't make sense. You aren't *under* rain, for example; the rain is falling all around you. You're in the midst of it.

Comment: Thank you for replying @WendiKidd. QA is a testing system(or the way software working environment, such as Linux ,MacOS and Microsoft.), well, what i was trying to ask is 'Background images fail to dispaly in/under QA(system/enviroment).' Does it make sences now?

Comment: @Ray-Von-Mice Ahh, do you perhaps mean something like this? "During QA testing we discovered that the background image is missing." (I realize there is no "in" or "under" there, but if this is what you mean then I don't think you need either!)

Comment: uhhh @WendiKidd ...before my project being tested, it's gonna be deployed in two different servers. One call QA, the other one call Production. So QA and Production are tow working environments, they are mostly same but some tiny respective feature.

Comment: @Ray-Von-Mice "The background image is missing on the QA server" / "The background image is missing in the QA environment"